# Add the user name, as default in the footer of a powerpoint template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates, footers

In a PowerPoint template footer we can add the date, the page numbers, but is there a way to also add the user name as a variable depending on who creates the presentation?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the duplicate, however I now notice the question and answer are 7 years old, is it also the case on PowerPoint 2010 and above?
I am using PowerPoint 2010

Comment: Still a duplicate ... there haven't been any changes in how you can use document properties (other than the UI for it having become better hidden)